# Range of the product of two operators

Tags: operator-theory

Is the Range of the product of two operators with closed range have closed range?
What extra conditions must we impose?

Answer (score 0):

In the following paper, an example is given of a bounded operator $T$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$, such that the range of $T$ is closed but the range of $T^2$ is not closed.

> Barnes, Bruce A.  Restrictions of bounded linear operators: Closed range.   *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **135** (2007), 1735-1740.  [Open access](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-06/S0002-9939-06-08624-2/).